# KerasTensor: difficulty handling the data type

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have embedded_sequences that are tensors. My ultimate goal is to pass them to a neural network model. But have an error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv1d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, None)
```

I have tried a bunch of methods to get the input format of the model right but with no success. Hence, my ask here :)

I am going to present a taste of my unsuccessful tries to get a sense of the issue.

1-One of the solution was to convert my kerastensor into a numpy array. I first made sure to have a proper kerastensor as opposed to a symbolic kerastensor. Then I converted the kerastensor into a numpy array. To ultimately, be able to input a "more user friendly" data format into the neural network. In code, I used the following commands:

```
embedded_sequences = tf.convert_to_tensor(embedded_sequences, dtype=tf.float32)
    
numpy_array_embedded_sequences = tf.make_ndarray(embedded_sequences)
```

```
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'
```

2-I even wanted to evaluate the kerastensor with no success:

```
embedded_sequences_value = embedded_sequences.eval()
```

```
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

OR like that

```
embedded_sequences_value = tf.keras.backend.get_value(embedded_sequences)
```

```
AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
size = 10
n_embeds = 5
embeddings_seq = np.random.randn(size,n_embeds)

class SeqModel(tf.keras.Model):

def __init__(self):
super().__init__()
self.conv1D = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(2,2, activation=tf.nn.relu)
self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

def call(self, x):
x = self.conv1D(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = self.dense(x)
return x

model = SeqModel()

embedded_sequences = tf.convert_to_tensor(embeddings_seq, dtype=tf.float32)
model(tf.expand_dims(embedded_sequences,axis=0))
```

although you shouldnt use tf.convert_to_tensor. model.fit in keras allows you to pass numpy array
or you should use a dataload like td.data,Dataset
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset